# How can I send a data and receive back with a button click with jscript ajax from servlet

Tags: java, json, ajax, http, servlets

I have a textfield and a button. when I click the button I want to send the textfield data to servlet and same time servlet sends relative data retrieved from the database to the ajax.

Here I need both post and get method.
Can you please help me with that?

Comment: user3049602 welcome to stackoverflow. Your question needs a lot improvement. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should first try something by yourself and ask only explicit questions including some sourcecode.

Comment: thanks for the advice.